# Extra trailing line in grok learning

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I've been going through the GYM of grok learning and I encountered a strange mess up. I have my code here which prints `"__"` in between each letter of the word but after I print it, grok prints an extra line under it which means i'm not able to finish the exercise. Here's the code:

```
c = input("Enter a word: ")
b = ''
for i in c:
    b = b + i + "__"
    print(b)
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what the incorrect output looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`:

input() actually evaluates the input as Python code.raw_input() returns the verbatim string entered by the user.

```
c = raw_input("Enter a word: ")
b = ''
for i in c:
    b = b + i + "__"
    print(b)
```

---

Output:

```
Enter a word: saket
s__
s__a__
s__a__k__
s__a__k__e__
s__a__k__e__t__
```

Comment: Python 3 does not use raw_input(), unless you're on an a pretty old release.  input() works fine, I think his issue lies in the implementation.  Personally, I would just use '__'.join(), but I suppose that's not the point of the exercise =)